# HTML subscribe form

Tags: php, html

I wrote code to get the subscription of my user who will write their email id in the form box but not getting the code.

My main code for HTML subscription form is

```
<form action="subscribe.php" class="subscribe" id="subscribe">
  <input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email" class="email form_item requiredField" name="subscribe_email" />
  <input type="submit" class='form_submit' value="subscribe" />
  <div id="form_results"></div>
</form>
```

I have made subscribe.php and write the code as well
but I am not getting the subscribe email on my desired email id what to do?

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
    $to_email = "rest@gmail.com"; //Recipient email, Replace with own email here

    //check if its an ajax request, exit if not
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {

        $output = json_encode(array( //create JSON data
            'type'=>'error',
            'text' => 'Sorry Request must be Ajax POST'
        ));
        die($output); //exit script outputting json data
    }

    $name = 'Rest';

    //proceed with PHP email.
    $headers = 'From: '.$name.'' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '.$email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    //Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
    $email     = filter_var($_POST["subscribe_email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Thank you. Your email was sent successfully.'));

    $send_mail = @mail($to_email, '', 'You have a new subscriber '.$email , $headers); 

    die($output);

    if(!$send_mail) {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.'));
        die($output);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Add `method="POST"` to your form element...  Form is using GET as default.

Comment: the php code appears to want only data submitted via ajax and you have not detailed the javascript function ( if there is one ) that sends the ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the ajax script in your code: should be something like this

First include a jquery library

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then the ajax code

```
<script>
$(function(){
$(document).on("click", ".form_submit", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

//validate 
var emailz = $("#email").val();

var emailp = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;

if (email=='')
{
alert("Please enter your email address");

}
else if (!emailp.test(emailz))
{
alert("Please enter a valid email");

}
else {              
    //Built a url to send
    var info = $("#subscribe").serialize();

    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "subscribe.php",
        data: info,
        success: function(result){          
            //$("#form")[0].reset();
              $('#form_results').html(html); 
        }
    });     
    e.preventDefault(); 
    }
});

});
</script>
```

Then followed by your HTML but i have added an id to your email textbox for validation

```
<form action="subscribe.php" class="subscribe" id="subscribe">
<input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email" id="email" class="email form_item requiredField" name="subscribe_email" />
<input type="submit" class='form_submit' value="subscribe" />
<div id="form_results"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: I m not getting any subscriber email id on my desired id after changing the code accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon the method of submitting the form you might need to change the html slightly. If you are using a traditional submit button then you'll need to add the method ( as method='post' ) to the form but if instead you are using ajax then I'd suggest changing the submit button to a `button` and assigning the event listener to it ( where the event listener does the ajax request )

```
<form action="subscribe.php" class="subscribe" id="subscribe" method="post">
  <input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email" class="email form_item requiredField" name="subscribe_email" required />
  <!--
    if you need to use ajax then this should be changed to a standard `button` and a suitable
    javascript listener attached either inline or on pageload in the head.
  -->
  <input type="submit" class='form_submit' value="subscribe" />

  <div id="form_results"></div>
</form>



<?php
    $useajax=false;/* set as true to use ajax once form & javascript are setup */
    $email=false;

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ) {

        $to_email = "rest@gmail.com";
        $name = 'Rest';

        $messages=(object)array(
            'method'    =>  array( 'type' => 'error',   'text' => 'Sorry, Request must be Ajax POST' ),
            'success'   =>  array( 'type' => 'message', 'text' => 'Thank you. Your email was sent successfully.' ),
            'failed'    =>  array( 'type' => 'error',   'text' => 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.' )
        );


        if( $useajax ) {
            if( !isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] ) && strtolower( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] ) != 'xmlhttprequest' ) {
                exit( json_encode( $messages->method ) );
            }
        }

        $email  = filter_var( filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'subscribe_email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL ), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL );
        if( $email ){

            $headers = "From: {$name}
                        Reply-To: {$email}
                        X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

            $subject = 'New subscriber';
            $message = 'You have a new subscriber '.$email;
            $result = @mail( $to_email, $subject, $message , $headers ); 
        }

        $output=$result ? $messages->success : $messages->failed;

        exit( json_encode( $output ) );
    }
?>
```

Comment: It's not working.. I am not getting any subscriber email on my business mail id... Code is not working... I guess

Comment: what does happen? what method are you using to submit the form?

Comment: what does happend? How far into the script do it get? What does it show - any errors? I just tested this and ( other than sending the email which I have disabled to test ) it outputs what I would expect - using standard for msubmission NOT ajax ~ so are you using ajax or not?

Comment: I am using Ajax still its not working properly not showing any error. I was expecting that the subscription mail id should come into my desired email address but i am not getting that output. I possible can you please show me screenshot while you using the same code and you are getting subscription email id into your desired email id...